# jquery slideToggle has a strange jump to it

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

If you look at this page

[newdemo4.virtual-showroom.com](http://newdemo4.virtual-showroom.com/)

When the "this site uses cookies" panel appears, if you click the "I wish to know more" link, the opening panel opens too far and then snaps back to it's proper size. I can't understand why? I've removed all padding and margins, tried setting positioning to relative and tried fixing a width.

I'm just using slideToggle, nothing fancy.

Anybody know why it's doing this please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide javascript being used

Comment: seemed to work fine if I gave `cookieMoreInfo` a fixed width of 500px;

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this to **cookieMoreInfo** class, it should work fine :

```
height: 100%;
```

Should look like this :

```
<div class="cookieMoreInfo" style="display: block; height: 100%;">...
```

Even better if you just define a specific height (say `300px`).

Comment: It still jumps for me. Although in a different way: it opens just a bit, then it jumps to its full height.

Comment: Actually I ended up having to set a fixed width to the hidden panel. This video was quite helpful explaining why this happens. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2263-Use-jQuery-s-SlideDown-With-Fixed-Width-Elements-To-Prevent-Jumping.htm